# Pandas transpose concat()

Tags: python, pandas

How to transpose a `DataFrame` returned by `concat()` ?

```
df = DataFrame([
            dict(a=1, b=10, c=41),
            dict(a=1, b=20, c=42),
            ])

concat([df, df]).T
```

I get :

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtypes' !
```

If I try :

```
concat([df, df]).T.to_dict()
```

I get :

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

I think this is related to the duplicates introduced by `concat()` in the index but didn't find a workaround.

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I used to unittest DataFrame values with df.T.to_dict().values()

Comment: fyi latest pandas release is able to support index duplicates, i believe before 0.8.0 this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify hierarchical index using `keys`:

```
In [288]: concatenated = concat([df,df], keys=['first', 'second'])

In [289]: print concatenated.T
   first      second    
       0   1       0   1
a      1   1       1   1
b     10  20      10  20
c     41  42      41  42

In [290]: print concatenated.T.to_dict().values()
[{'a': 1, 'c': 41, 'b': 10}, {'a': 1, 'c': 41, 'b': 10}, {'a': 1, 'c': 42, 'b': 20}, {'a': 1, 'c': 42, 'b': 20}]
```

Comment: Ok, how to do this using the series names?